# split string to all options that can be

Tags: c#, string, split

I want to split string to all options that can be from 2 characters to the end.

example:

```
string temp = "abcdef";
```

output:

```
ab
bc
cd
de
ef
abc
bcd
cde
def
abcd
bcde
cdef
abcde
bcdef
abcdef
```

Comment: Off you go then. What's stopping you?

Answer (score 4):

Consider this implementation using an enumerator:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> Substrings(string input)
{
    for (int l = 2; l <= input.Length; l++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= input.Length - l; i++)
        {
            yield return input.Substring(i, l);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var str in Substrings("abcdef"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a fancy extension method:

```
static class StringExtensions {

  public static IEnumerable<String> SplitInParts(this String s, Int32 partLength) {
    if (s == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("s");
    if (partLength <= 0)
      throw new ArgumentException("Part length has to be positive.", "partLength");

    for (var i = 0; i < s.Length; i += partLength)
      yield return s.Substring(i, Math.Min(partLength, s.Length - i));
  }

}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
for (I = 2; I <= MyStr.Lenght; I++) 
{
  var parts = MyStr.SplitInParts(I);
  Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", parts));
}
```